# Strict comparison between two values

Tags: php

```
$a =1;
$b="1";
if($a!==$b){
   echo "true";
}
```

According to strict comparison the definition it should not run the if condition, because the value is same. So it shouldn't run the conditional code can any kindly tell me the reason why is that conditional code is getting true?

Comment: It should ___always___ run the condition, because `"1"` is ___never___ `1` by strict typing rules.... perhaps you meant `if($a === $b){
   echo "true";
}`

Answer (score 1):

when you use three = signs it means it compare value as well as the data type.. so you are usin two = sign and a ! not equal to sign means if the value is equal but the data type is not equal so the condition goes true..